# How does one disable the success message once the requied field message is shown?

Tags: asp.net

I have a form with two text boxes.  Once I enter the data and click the save button, I get a  message in label: indicating that it saved successfully.

Then I show the form again, but when I click on the save button, I get a message telling  me that it cannot be blank "as textbox value is empty this time" from the required field validator.

But I am still showing the message "data saved successfully," which should not happen.

How do I solve this issue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set ValidationGroup on your textboxes, requiredfieldvalidators, and buttons to the same value.  This will prevent (theoretically) the saving of blank values when the validators fire.

HOWEVER, do server-side validation too!  The above is easy to sidestep.

Comment: +1 because you actually knew what the heck he was talking about.

Comment: I think what he is saying is that, if the user gets all the values inputted correctly and saves the form, it posts back, saves the data and then reloads the page with a blank form and a "success" message. Now, if the user again tries to submit - the validators as they should and prevent the form from being submitted - BUT the "success" is still there from the previous post back.

He wants to know how to remove that client-side if validation fails.

Answer (score 0):

Off the the top of my head, my suggestion would be to add an "OnClientClick" event your save button that calls out to a script which hides the "success" message client-side. I'm not sure if there is a way to trigger client-side code when client-side validation fails - without using a CustomValidator, but I could be wrong.